# Is it possible to put brackets round a Forest tree?

Tags: linguistics, forest, semantics

I want to create a tree using `forest` with large `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` around it (semantic interpretation brackets). `schemabox` looks hopeful but doesn't seem to work.

How do I do this?

(Alternatively, is there another tree package I can use that can do this?)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

% big open double-bracket here
\begin{forest}
 [A tree] 
\end{forest}
% big close double-bracket here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think a mwe would be applicable itfp. Added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest,stmaryrd}
\begin{document}

$\left\llbracket
\begin{forest}
 [A tree] 
\end{forest}
\right\rrbracket$

\end{document}
```

A macro to do this, vertically centred:

```
\newcommand{\brr}[1]{
\left\llbracket\raisebox{-.5\height}{ #1 }
\right\rrbracket}
```

Use:

```
\begin{equation}
\brr{\begin{forest}[X]\end{forest}}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `bracketedforest` environment be useful?

Comment: I'm actually using this in an `equation` and the brackets extend a bit far down. It looks like there's a margin at the bottom of the tree. Any ideas?

Comment: @Joe tex delimiters always stretch same amount up and down so if teh box with the forest isn't vertically centred it will do that, you can always use `\left(\raisebox{-.5\height}{\begin{forest}...` or whatever vertical adjustment makes the brackets come out right

Comment: I turned both your pieces of advice into a macro and updated your answer, hope you don't mind!

Comment: Can't you avoid the `\raisebox` by using the `baseline` tikz option?

Comment: @Bordaigorl quite possibly: I know nothing about tikz:-)

Answer (score 2):

Since `forest` uses `tikz` you could simply do the drawing in `tikz`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}

\newcommand{\StubSize}{0.5em}%
\newcommand{\BraceForest}[1][]{%
    \begin{scope}[overlay]
        \coordinate (Left Start)  at ($(current bounding box.south west)+(\StubSize,0ex)$);
        \coordinate (Left End)    at ($(current bounding box.north west)+(\StubSize,0ex)$);
        \coordinate (Right Start) at ($(current bounding box.south east)-(\StubSize,0ex)$);
        \coordinate (Right End)   at ($(current bounding box.north east)-(\StubSize,0ex)$);
        \draw [#1] (Left Start) 
                -- (current bounding box.south west)
                -- (current bounding box.north west)
                -- (Left End);
        \draw [#1] (Right Start) 
                -- (current bounding box.south east)
                -- (current bounding box.north east)
                -- (Right End);
    \end{scope}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
 [A tree] 
 \BraceForest[red,ultra thick]%
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I think David Carlisle's answer looks a bit more canonical though! This may come in handy if the brackets get out of hand...